# Full text search to return any columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I want to search my database for any columns that has the text '%firefighter%' and return all the columns that contain that text.

I know that for full text search you need the column name, but what if I want sql to return all of the columns like an INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but instead of looking at the column name, i want to search just the text inside of the column.

Answer (score 0):

This [**snippet**](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm) should help you provided by Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. It searches all tables and columns looking for the value you provide. I personally have used this before and it works just fine.